# How do I register an Autofac "Adapter" that has dependencies?

Tags: c#, adapter, autofac

Autofac provides [RegisterAdapter](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/adapters-decorators.html#adapters), an easy way to wrap (or *adapt*) an implementation:

```cs
builder.RegisterAdapter<Meta<ICommand>, ToolbarButton>(
    cmd => new ToolbarButton(cmd.Value, (string)cmd.Metadata["Name"]));
```

This is cool, but what if my adapter constructor requires DI support?  Suppose my ToolbarButton constructor looks like this:

```cs
public ToolbarButton(ICommand cmd, IService1 svc1, IService2 svc2) { ... }
```

And I just want to inject my `ToolbarButton` collection as a composite, so I don't need metadata:

```cs
public Toolbar(IEnumerable<ToolbarButton> buttons) { ... }
```

So I'm looking for the best way to register my `ICommand` adapter. It *seems* like I should be able to do something like this, letting Autofac resolve dependent services for each adapter it creates:

```cs
builder.RegisterAdapter<ICommand, ToolbarButton>();
```

But there is no such signature for `RegisterAdapter()`.  (Why?)

So instead I'm having to do something like this, which seems kind of anti-patterny and redundant:

```cs
builder.RegisterAdapter<ICommand, ToolbarButton>((ctx, from) =>
    new ToolbarButton(from, ctx.Resolve<IService2>(), ctx.Resolve<IService2>()));
```

Or if I don't want to list out each of my dependencies, I can pass `ICommand` as a parameter:

```cs
builder.RegisterAdapter<ICommand, ToolbarButton>((ctx, from) =>
    ctx.Resolve<ToolbarButton>(new TypedParameter(typeof(ICommand), from)));
```

This is also ugly and, again, it feels like I'm telling Autofac stuff it should already know.  Is there a better way?

Comment: In which way is the last attempt with `Resolve` with `TypedParameter` "ugly"? You get the resolved instance with automatically injected dependencies and your "normal" required parameters.

Comment: "Ugly" might be a bad word choice, but the last two solutions don't give Autofac any additional information over the (imaginary) RegisterAdapter() option, yet they involve quite a bit more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It feels ugly but that's pretty much it. If it was a decorator rather than an adapter you'd get more "free magic," but since adapters can require more complex setup (it's not always just constructor parameters) all that's offered right now is what you've found: you have to do the work in the factory function.

If you have ideas for different behavior, you can always [open an issue](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues) with your proposal.